# /manual/cache folder on my server?

Tags: web-server, malware, search-engine

On our site's server, once managed by someone who's no longer with us, there's a folder named "/manual/cache" which contains txt files named+like+this, mostly using pornographic-related keywords. The content is mainly spam-like gibberish.

My assumption on the matter is that it's somehow used to spam search engines, but I might be wrong, which is the reason of my question here.

Any idea what it might mean/contain?

As an additionnal note, the person's hiring period oddly correspond to the dates of the files, which seem to have automagically stopped being generated after the date we parted ways.

Comment: Have you checked the public block-lists for your domain? he might have been sending email spam.. which could possibly go faster if you cached the crap you wanted to send.. although, surely the bandwidth would be the bottleneck.. write-protect it and wait a week, then rm it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close the file: It was gibberish, we deleted it, it never came back. Our best bet is that the dude really was doing weird stuff on our servers, there are no logs of it or anything. So yeah, not an answer, but our best bet still stands: search-engine spam + maybe e-mail spam.